# What is difference between %WinDir% and %SystemRoot%?

Tags: windows-7, path

What is difference between %Windir% and %Systemroot% in Windows Path Location?
Both of them show "Windows" folder location.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To expand upon Mr. Dave’s answer, `%SystemRoot%` is a *built-in* variable (along with a small handful of others like `%SystemDrive%`). That is, it is not actually defined in the environment variable store at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` in the registry.

On the other hand, `%windir%` is a regular variable and is defined in the variable store as `%SystemRoot%`. (There is no “real variable” counterpart to `%SystemDrive%`.)

Which to use doesn’t really matter, but you *may* run into problems with variable expansion in batch-files, in which case you could try the other one. (I don’t recall having problems with this specifically, but it’s worth keeping in mind.)

In addition, `%SystemRoot%` (and `%SystemDrive%`) are set during the installation process (when you choose the destination drive) and is thus available from the earliest point when Windows is being installed whereas `%windir%` is set at a later point during the install, so if you are creating some sort of custom installation (e.g., OEM, PE, etc.), you will want to use `%SystemRoot%`.

Comment: So, %windir% built AFTER installation?

Comment: No, during installation, but after `%SystemRoot%`. Windows has enough information to set `SystemDrive` and `SystemRoot` as soon as you choose the drive where to install it (plus it uses a default if you don’t modify the destination). It sets several default environment variables (including `windir`) later in the installation when it initializes the registry. This only matters if you are modifying the installation process.

Comment: in which case you could try *the other one*.  I assume *the other one* is `%windir%`. Is that correct?

Comment: [Recognized Environment Variables: SYSTEMROOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables#:~:text=18%20%5BProfileImagePath%5D.-,SYSTEMROOT,-Same%20as%20WINDIR)

Answer (score 35):

On Win 7 `%SystemRoot%` is a read-only system variable while `%windir%` can be changed and is set by default as `windir=%SystemRoot%` . The OS relies on `%SystemRoot%`. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Microsoft_Windows), `%WinDir%` pre-dates Windows NT and seems to be superseded by `%SystemRoot%`.

Answer (score 0):

For maximum batch compatibility %windir% is preferable (ie: running in an old windows on a virtual machine). %windir% will also work on win 3.11, win95, win95 and winME. Otherwise they are basically the same.