# How do I fix the errors listed in this CheckSUR.log file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, dism

I'm trying to update my Windows 7 machine using Windows Updates but I'm continually getting error 800B0100 (similar to whats reported [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-800b0100#1TC=windows-7), [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-update-error-code-800b0100/9197bb6c-7dca-427b-8a54-7c9a7bfe05d8?auth=1), and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-update-error-0x00b0100-and-cryptographic/aab184f4-a02c-4798-b285-c34b19e2ae8f)). After taking several steps mentioned in those guides (system update readiness tool, check disk, Windows Update Troubeshooter, DISM, sfc, maybe something else I forgot). I've come up mostly empty-handed.

The only lead I've got comes from the `DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth` command I ran. That produced [this](http://pastebin.com/ZkQ3gCGK) CheckSUR.log file. Some highlights:

```
Checking Windows Servicing Packages

Checking Package Manifests and Catalogs
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x00000000  servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~11.2.9412.0.mum       Expected file name Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~neutral~~11.2.9412.0.mum does not match the actual file name
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x00000000  servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~11.2.9412.0.mum      Expected file name Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~neutral~~11.2.9412.0.mum does not match the actual file name
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x800F0900  servicing\Packages\Package_111_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.mum        Line 1: 
(f) CBS Catalog Corrupt 0x800B0100  servicing\Packages\Package_111_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.cat        
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x800F0900  servicing\Packages\Package_112_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.mum        Line 1: 

...

Checking Package Watchlist

Checking Component Watchlist

Checking Packages

Checking Component Store
(f) CSI Manifest All Zeros  0x00000000  winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-wow64_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23136_none_c6c193f2071b07e3.manifest   amd64_microsoft-windows-wow64_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23136_none_c6c193f2071b07e3 
(f) CSI Manifest All Zeros  0x00000000  winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-ncrypt-dll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23136_none_bc7a217a2167e4bd.manifest  amd64_microsoft-windows-ncrypt-dll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23136_none_bc7a217a2167e4bd    
(f) CSI Manifest All Zeros  0x00000000  winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-ntdll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23136_none_b772aa2a2bf98230.manifest   amd64_microsoft-windows-ntdll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23136_none_b772aa2a2bf98230 
(f) CSI Manifest All Zeros  0x00000000  winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-smss_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23136_none_0ad673e548fd75d4.manifest    amd64_microsoft-windows-smss_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23136_none_0ad673e548fd75d4  
(f) CSI Manifest All Zeros  0x00000000  winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-rpc-http_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23136_none_fe94b8d86f1fbfc8.manifest    amd64_microsoft-windows-rpc-http_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23136_none_fe94b8d86f1fbfc8  

...

servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~11.2.9412.0.mum
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~11.2.9412.0.mum
    servicing\packages\Package_111_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.mum
    servicing\packages\Package_111_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.mum
    servicing\packages\Package_112_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.mum
    servicing\packages\Package_112_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.mum
    servicing\packages\Package_113_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.mum
    servicing\packages\Package_113_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.mum
    servicing\packages\Package_114_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.mum
```

How can I fix this errors so the next time I run `DISM` I dont get them? I'm hoping that that will fix my original error (with the 800B0100 error code on Windows Update), so as an alternative if you have a fix for that I would be much more grateful.

Comment: The corrupted files are not the source of your inability to update Windows.  You cannot use DISM on Windows 7 to repair your installation that only works on Windows 8 or above.

Comment: @Ramhound Perhaps I can not use DISM to repair the files, but Im pretty sure the corrupt files are still the source of my issues.

Comment: The only way you can solve this is by creating your own .WIM image of a fully patched Windows 7 installation running an identical version as your current installation then running SFC against that .WIM image.  But the listed corruption I still insit would not prevent Windows from updating.  [KB3040272](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3040272) has to deal with long name catalog files.  IE apparently has some slight corruption.  What you have listed indicates to me while you have pretty sever system integrity corruption it isn't the cause of your inability to update currently.

Comment: I hope that you downloaded the System Update Readiness Tool [from here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-the-system-update-readiness-tool), since not running the latest version may not recognize all the packages and may cause bogey error messages. In any case, the CheckSUR.log errors may not relate to your Windows Update problem - on my computer DISM finds 4 errors, but Windows Update works fine. Try first to reset Windows Update components as [described here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058) (for running the Fixit use IE).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Intro

[`DISM`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2966583) will only repair the corrupt updates if it has access to the "good" versions of the updates in the proper subdirectory of `%WINDIR%\Temp\CheckSUR\`. Without those files, [`DISM`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2966583) or System Update and Readiness Tool [(`SURT`)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) will only generate a listing of corrupted files encountered and will not actually perform any repairs (as you witnessed).

So, how do you go about identifying the corrupt files and then fixing them? This [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) does a reasonable job describing it, albeit with a few broken links and missing details, which are mostly addressed in this [other MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2700601). Frustratingly, some of the information conflicts with this [MS technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee619779.aspx)<sup>*(see footnote)</sup>. Assuming you'd rather read about the procedure here rather than stitch together several different sources....

## Steps to identify bad updates

In `%WINDIR%\Logs\CBS\CheckSUR.log`, generated by installing [SURT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2966583) or running [DISM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2966583), skip to the bottom of the file and read the lines that begin with `servicing\packages\Package_` in the `Unavailable repair files:` section. Where you see **_for_KB***######*, KB###### (in your case [KB3040272](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3040272)) is the update that you'll want to download. @magicandre1981 also identified [KB3071756](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3071756) as affecting you, presumably from a portion of your log file not directly provided in the question.

## Download the non-corrupt version of packages

Once you've identified the broken KBs, you can obtain Microsoft Update `MSU` files at the relevant KB entry on [support.microsoft.com (/kb/######)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) or, using IE, going to the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Thanks.aspx?id=140) and searching for the relevant KB number. On the MS KB page, scroll down to the "Update information" section and look for a link that says "Download the package now." next to a link for your flavor of operating system (x86 = 32 bit OS; x64 = standard 64 bit; ia-64 only for high end intel 64 bit servers). Download the file.

## Making update files available for DISM/SURT

After downloading the files, you can place the whole MSU as indicated below, or you can extract all `mum`, `cat` and `manifest` files contained and then moving the "good" version of the corrupt packages indicated by CheckSUR.log into the appropriate directory (again, as indicated below). The extraction from an msu file can be performed with the following [command sequence](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934307).

```
expand -f:* C:\path\to\msu.msu %temp%\msuexpanded\
expand -f:* %temp\msuexpanded\Windows6.1-KBnnnnnn-xnn.cab %temp\msuexpanded\cab\
```

`update.cat` and `update.mum` should be renamed to the name specific to the package - for example for your [broken package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3040272), you would rename the `update.cat` as `Package_for_KB3040272~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1.cat`.

You should then move the files (msu and/or the other extensions) into place from the %temp\msuexpanded\cab\ directory<sup>*(see footnote)</sup>:

```
File Extension | Absolute path (create if needed) | OS version confirmed (by)
-------------- | -------------------------------- | -----
msu            | %SYSTEMROOT%\CheckSUR\packages\  | Windows 7 SP1 x64 (@chadnt‡)
```

(see footnote for symbols)

```
File Extension | Subdirectory of %WINDIR%\Temp\CheckSUR\ (create if needed)
-------------- | -------
cat            | servicing\Packages\
mum            | servicing\Packages\
manifest       | winsxs\Manifests\
msu (alternate)| Packages\
```

Both `%SYSTEMROOT%` and `%WINDIR%` [default to C:\WINDOWS](https://superuser.com/a/638335/319748)

If the repairing files are in the proper directory, DISM/SURT should now repair corrupted files.

## Repairing corrupted files

After [KB2966583](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2966583) - **Improvements for the System Update Readiness tool in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2** ([KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2966583) | [`MSU` download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=cd262d11-36ab-4e2e-a740-238e4f82b2b5)) has been installed, the command-line version "DISM" becomes available.

DISM becomes the command-line invokable version of CheckSUR aka System Update Readiness Tool [(SURT)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) in Windows7, so that you don't need to "install" SURT from [MS KB 947821](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) every time you need to check/repair corrupted MS Updates.

Usage of DISM is as follows

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth
```

Which must be run from an Administrator account (i.e. the Admin/elevated command-prompt or the start bar with elevated privileges).

Or you can always install [SURT from KB947821](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) again.

After DISM or SURT has been run again, check your CheckSUR.log file again and see if it has addressed your broken packages. If it didn't work, you may wish to consider doing an [Inplace Update](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html) of Windows.

*Disclaimer: portions of this lifted from @magicandre1981 's response. As I added so many details, I no longer felt that a simple edit of his post was in order.*

## Footnotes

<sup>*</sup>Regarding directories, conflicting information is given on Microsoft's website:

1. [KB947821](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) (Step 4 of "How to Fix") says `msu` should be copied
   to `%SYSTEMROOT%\CheckSUR\packages`
2. [KB2700601](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2700601) says `msu`,
   `mum` and `cat` to `%WinDir%\Temp\CheckSUR\Packages\`
3. [MS Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee619779.aspx) says (after typo correction) `mum` and `cat` files go in
   `%windir%\Temp\CheckSUR\servicing\packages`

Similarly there are several locations identified as the appropriate directory for `manifest` files

[† @mpag](https://superuser.com/users/319748/mpag)
[‡ @chadnt](https://superuser.com/users/726416/chadnt)

Comment: I initially placed my `msu` in the `%WinDir%\Temp\CheckSUR\Packages` folder but it was not used.  Moving it to `%SYSTEMROOT%\CheckSUR\packages` folder worked.

Comment: @chadnt it seems that KB947821 was most accurate then, at least for you.  Could you comment on which operating system (and 32 vs 64-bit) you use?

Comment: I had success placing the `msu` file in `%SYSTEMROOT%\CheckSUR\packages` per KB947821 for a repair on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

try to [install the update KB2966583](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=cd262d11-36ab-4e2e-a740-238e4f82b2b5):

**Improvements for the System Update Readiness tool in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2966583/en-us

It should now allow you to run this DISM command to repair corrupted files:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth
```

*(I never tried if this really works. Please try it and report back)*

If this doesn't work, do the following. Because files of the Updates [KB3040272](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=47631) and [KB3071756](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48444) are damaged, download the MSU files from the downloadcenter, put them into the folder `%SYSTEMROOT%\CheckSUR\packages` and run the [checksur tool KB947821](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821) again.

if this still doesn't fix your issue, repair your Windows via [Inplace Update](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

Comment: It says I already have this installed.

Comment: now try to run the DISM command and see what happens.

Comment: Generated the same log file with errors. Perhaps you mean the `DISM` command with /RestoreHealth or something? If so, it doesn't work on Windows 7 I believe (only win8+ or something like that).

Comment: Afaik the  /RestoreHealth parameter was not backported, only the Scanhealth which should do the repair. I see that files of the Updates KB3040272, KB3071756 are damaged. Point checksur to use the CAB/MSU of the update by coping the MSU/CABs to  %windir%\Temp\CheckSUR\servicing\packages and run checksur again.

Comment: Where do I get the MSU/CABs? And when you say run checksur again, do you mean `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth`?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - You manually download them from Microsoft's website.

Comment: after downloading the MSU files from Download center and placing them in the folder **%SYSTEMROOT%\CheckSUR\packages** run the normal checksur tool from KB947821.

Comment: have you tried what I told you? Have you placed the MSU files in the location and run KB947821 again?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've created a "new" answer with portions lifted from your answer. Feel free to merge whatever you wish of my answer into yours and I can delete mine.